# Can bounds(co-ordinates) be used while identifying an element on an Android App?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

Can something like this work? Well, it's not working for me. Guys, what's the right-est way of making it work? Need Help   (Appium version - 1.4.0.0 and Selenium 2.4.5)

```
dr.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@bounds='[9,288][144,318]']"))
  .click();
```

Answer (score 9):

Try below code, it works for me...

```
WebElement abc = driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//android.widget.ImageButton[@bounds='[9,288][144,318]']"))

abc.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. But yet helped me to swipe from right to left, for what I was roaming all over the internet.

```
TouchAction t = new TouchAction(dr);
WebElement from = dr.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@bounds='[354,2232][539,2263]']");
WebElement to = dr.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@bounds='[0,2232][181,2263]']");
t.longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(from)).withDuration(ofSeconds(2))).moveTo(element(to)).release().perform();
```